# ionic 4 file chooser not allowing to select multiple PDF files

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I wanted to select multiple PDF files from the local(gallery).

I'm using Ionic 4 "File Chooser" (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser) to select files. From the "file chooser" I can select ONLY one PDF file. But I wanted to select multiple PDF files.

Is this possible? If not what are the alternative solutions to select multiple PDF files from the Gallery.

Thanks in advance.